# Embed unique identifier in Chart.js segments?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to make my pie-chart interactive by allowing the user to double-click on a slice to drill down. I believe that the way to do this is to create an onclick handler on the canvas, and use `getSegmentsAtEvent()` to determine which slice was clicked.

The segment data returned by the call to `getSegmentsAtEvent()` is possibly ambiguous though. Here is a sample of the returned data:

```
[{
    "circumference": 4.1887902047863905,
    "endAngle": 8.901179185171081,
    "fillColor": "#FF5A5E",
    "highlightColor": "#FF5A5E",
    "innerRadius": 0,
    "label": "Red",
    "outerRadius": 99.5,
    "showStroke": true,
    "startAngle": 4.71238898038469,
    "strokeColor": "#fff",
    "strokeWidth": 2,
    "value": 300
}]
```

Of those fields, only `value`, `fillColor`, `highlightColor`, and `label` are supplied by me, and none of them are necessarily unique. I could ensure that `label` is unique, but that might make it less readable for humans.

I have tried adding an additional property (e.g. "id") into the data I pass into `Pie()`, but it is stripped out when I get the segment data back from this call. Is there a way to add a property to each segment which I can use to positively identify them, without overloading the `label` field?

Comment: hi was the below answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need to either override the pie chart or create a new chart type that inherits from pie.

Here is an example of a new chart type, i have passed a new attribute called id and then the only thing that needs to be different in this chart is that when the data is being added this id needs to passed to the chart

```js
Chart.types.Pie.extend({
    name: "PieUnique",
    addData: function (segment, atIndex, silent) {
        var index = atIndex || this.segments.length;
        this.segments.splice(index, 0, new this.SegmentArc({
            value: segment.value,
            outerRadius: (this.options.animateScale) ? 0 : this.outerRadius,
            innerRadius: (this.options.animateScale) ? 0 : (this.outerRadius / 100) * this.options.percentageInnerCutout,
            fillColor: segment.color,
            highlightColor: segment.highlight || segment.color,
            showStroke: this.options.segmentShowStroke,
            strokeWidth: this.options.segmentStrokeWidth,
            strokeColor: this.options.segmentStrokeColor,
            startAngle: Math.PI * this.options.startAngle,
            circumference: (this.options.animateRotate) ? 0 : this.calculateCircumference(segment.value),
            label: segment.label,
            //add option passed
            id: segment.id
        }));
        if (!silent) {
            this.reflow();
            this.update();
        }
    },
});

var pieData = [{
    value: 300,
    color: "#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red",
    id: "1-upi"
}, {
    value: 50,
    color: "#46BFBD",
    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
    label: "Green",
    id: "2-upi"
}, {
    value: 100,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    highlight: "#FFC870",
    label: "Yellow",
    id: "3-upi"
}, {
    value: 40,
    color: "#949FB1",
    highlight: "#A8B3C5",
    label: "Grey",
    id: "4-upi"
}, {
    value: 120,
    color: "#4D5360",
    highlight: "#616774",
    label: "Dark Grey",
    id: "5-upi"
}

];


var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
window.myPie = new Chart(ctx).PieUnique(pieData);

document.getElementById("chart-area").onclick = function (evt) {
    var activePoints = window.myPie.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
    //you can now access the id at activePoints[0].id
    console.log(activePoints);


};
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/leighquince/Chart.js/master/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart-area" width="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Big thanks! Works great with Doughnut charts. addData() Method taken from Chart.js source.

Comment: note that if you don't have the `options.startAngle` set, the chart won't show up. the default value (from the source code) is `Math.PI * 1.5`

Answer (score 2):

To get an slice that was clicked on, getElementAtEvent can be used. Worked for me!

```
 stackedBar(datasets) {
    var c = $("#canvas-bar");
    var ctx = c[0].getContext("2d");
    let __this = this;
    this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: ["something"],
        datasets: datasets,
      },
      options: {
        onClick: function (e, item) {
          __this.onClickAction(e, item);
        },
        title: {},
        legend: {},
        scales: {}
      }
    });
  }

 onClickAction(event, elements) {
    if (elements && elements.length) {
      let selected = this.chart.getElementAtEvent(event)[0];
      let sliceIndex = selected['_datasetIndex'];
    }
  }
```