# Chart.js attach extra data

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have a pie chart that I want to attach a URL to, so I can navigate to it when clicked. However, I can't find any way to attach extra data to the chart, so that I can find the section of the pie chart that was clicked.

Is there a way to do this?

```
var data = [{
    value: 100,
    color: "#00ff00",
    label: 'Label',
    url : '/Account/1'
},
    //etc
];

var ctx = chart.get(0).getContext("2d");
var balChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, options);

chart[0].onclick = function(evt){
    var activePoints = balChart.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);

    var point = activePoints[0];
    var url = point.url; //undefined. How can I access more info about my data from this?
};
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ew6cp5t/)

Comment: you only have access to value, color, and label. you could try to search data and match those known properties in each item; if you find only 1 then you know which one to get the url from...

Comment: answered a similar question here about adding an id so could use the same technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377145/embed-unique-identifier-in-chart-js-segments

Comment: @Quince that looks like it'll work perfectly! thanks!