# How to fix bars in Chart.js with long labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I use Chart.js( Version: 2.7.2 ) in my application and some labels in resulting rows are rather long

```
        var barCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasVoteNames");
        var ctx = barCanvas.getContext('2d');

        var numberWithCommas = function(x) {
            return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        };
        var self = this;
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {  // stacked bar report https://jsfiddle.net/sdfx/hwx9awgn/
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels:monthsXCoordItems,
                datasets: [

                    {
                        label: 'Correct Votes',
                        data: voteValuesCorrect,
                        borderWidth: 1,           // The stroke width of the bar in pixels.

                        backgroundColor : formatColor('#05b932'), //rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), // The fill color of the bar. See Colors
                        borderColor: formatColor('#05b932'),// rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) // The color of the bar border.

                        hoverBackgroundColor : formatColor('#05b932'),   // The fill colour of the bars when hovered.
                        hoverBorderColor: formatColor('#05b932'),        //    The stroke colour of the bars when hovered.
                        hoverBorderWidth : 1                             //    The stroke width of the bars when hovered.
                    },

                    {
                        label: 'Incorrect Votes',
                        data: voteValuesNoneCorrect,
                        borderWidth: 1,           // The stroke width of the bar in pixels.

                        backgroundColor : formatColor('#b1a19a'), //rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), // The fill color of the bar. See Colors
                        borderColor: formatColor('#b1a19a'),// rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) // The color of the bar border.
                        hoverBackgroundColor : formatColor('#b1a19a'),   // The fill colour of the bars when hovered.
                        hoverBorderColor: formatColor('#b1a19a'),        //    The stroke colour of the bars when hovered.
                        hoverBorderWidth : 1                             //    The stroke width of the bars when hovered.
                    },

                ]
            },

            options: { // options of Report By Vote Names
                animation: {
                    duration: 10,
                },

                tooltips: { // tooltip text of Report By Vote Days ( 'bar' report )
                    mode: 'label',
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + numberWithCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel);
                        }
                    }
                }, // tooltips: { // tooltip text of Report By Vote Days ( 'bar' report )

                scales: { // options for x and y scales
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,    // Stacked bar charts can be used to show how one data series i
                        gridLines: { display: false },
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,  // Stacked bar charts can be used to show how one data series i
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function(value) { // on Y scale show only integer without decimals
                                if (Math.floor(value) === value) {
                                    return value;
                                }
                            },  // callback: function(value) { return numberWithCommas(value); },
                        },
                    }],
                }, // scales: { // options for x and y scales
                legend: {display: true}
            } // options: { // options of Report By Vote Names

        }); // var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {  // stacked bar report https://jsfiddle.net/sdfx/hwx9awgn/

}
```

The chart I got is what I need 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yejn.jpg
but with long labels for any bar it does not look good and I did not find if there is a way to fix it somehow ?
Why labels has big marging, not as relative bars?

Some options for xAxes or additive legends?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I still search for some decision . I googled and found several examples, but they all with short labels and no problems similar mine... No ideas?

Comment: I found a similar example and modified some labels to repeate my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/hwx9awgn/1259/
some labels on xAxes are not showm at all : actually  1,3,5... labels are shown
can be any decision?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

***You were using ChartJs version 2.1.3 in your JSFiddle, which does not seem to handle multiline labels***

You can use multilines labels with the following solutions:

```
var dates = [["Some l-o-o-o-o-", "o-o-o-o-o-o-o-", "n-n-n-n-n-n-g-g-g-", "g-g-g-g label"], "DDD", ["EEE", "FFF", "GGG"], "HHH", "III"];
```

You can replace a label by an array, and each element of the array will be considered as a new line (See JSFiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/cyuwxh3q/

---

If your labels are generated dinamically, you can split them with a plugin in your chart configuration :

```
type: 'bar',
data: {...},
options: {...},
plugins: [{
    beforeInit: function (chart) {
        chart.data.labels.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
            var a = [];
            a.push(value.slice(0, 5));
            var i = 1;
            while(value.length > (i * 5)){
                a.push(value.slice(i * 5, (i + 1) * 5));
                i++;
            }
            array[index] = a;
        })
    }
}]
```

This function will turn each label into an array of element which length is less or equal to the given value (here 5) (See JSFiddle) : https://jsfiddle.net/jhr5nm17/

---

Those are two easy ways to handle long labels by replacing them by multiline labels, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I searched!
Also are some parameters to change width beetween bar elements on xAxes?

Comment: You can add a barThickness property in options: { scales: { xAxes: [{ barThickness: value, ... }] } }

Comment: I found one more problem :
I made popup dialog opened by click on slice and to define which slice is clicked I saved id/name of items
in array and made search by name of label. Now  that does not work, as text of label is array.
Sure I can make by concatenated array string, but if there is some better decision, like user's defined tag for any slice?

Comment: You will need to override the chart , see this question for more informations : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377145/embed-unique-identifier-in-chart-js-segments. If this does not suit you, consider writing a new question to get more answers. And if the answer provided here helped you to resolve your problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @Ivan If this answer solved your problem, please don't forget to Accept it.

Comment: Why not customize labels so they only show on hover? Shouldn't be too much work. I think the angle display is quite gaughty IMHO. I used the hover technique with a popup label when using chart.js. Or you could use the dotdotdot technique which would be ugly on an angle. Why not customize labels so they only show on hover? Shouldn't be too much work. I think the angle display is quite gaughty IMHO. I used the hover technique with a popup label when using chart.js http://i53.photobucket.com/albums/g67/yardpenalty/Screenshot%202_zpsur4qlxm7.png

Comment: This is amazing :)